# Requests exception with only multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, multiprocessing, python-requests

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def get_total_pages():
    tut = []
    base_url = 'Your group '
    for url in [base_url % i for i in range(1, 27)]:
        tut.append(url)
    print(tut)
    #get_data_from_page(tut)
    pool = ThreadPool(8)
    results = pool.map(get_data_from_page, tut)

def get_data_from_page(tut):
    f = open("emails.txt", 'a')
    email = []
    for a in tut:
        link = s.get(a).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
        links = soup.find('div', class_="mens").find_all('span', class_="inviz")
        for e in links:
            emails = e.text
            f.write(emails + ', ')
            email.append(emails)
    print(email)

def main():
    get_total_pages()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This results in an error saying it only works with multiprocessing, and:

```
raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
```

Comment: can you quickly explain why you want to do this? It makes the impression as you are a spammer trying to harvest email addresses from the internet

Comment: fix indent, legibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was in this

```
 for a in tut:
  link = s.get(a).text
```

and was needed

just

```
link = s.get(a).text
#without for
```